# Convert character to a Factor with numeric values other than 1, 2, 3 to calculate score

Tags: r, levels

In R, I have a dataframe with the answers to a questionnaire, and due to technical reasons the data could only be provided as the answer labels, so not the answer codes.

The answers can be `Never`, `Sometimes`, `Always` which corresponds with the answer codes `0`, `1`, `3`, and these codes can be used to calculate a total score.

I've isolated a test dataset (the full data has more columns) and the R syntax I've got so far.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
DateOfBirth,Sex,Question_01,Question_02,Question_03,Question_04
12-03-2001,M,Sometimes,Sometimes,Never,Never
21-08-1988,F,Always,Never,Always,Sometimes
30-11-1985,F,Always,Always,Sometimes,Never
01-04-2001,M,Sometimes,Sometimes,Never,Never
12-12-1986,M,Always,Sometimes,Always,Never
19-02-1982,F,Always,Always,Never,Sometimes
11-05-1980,M,Sometimes,Sometimes,Never,Never
01-06-2000,F,Always,Sometimes,Always,Always
20-11-1981,F,Never,Never,Never,Sometimes
30-07-1982,M,Never,Never,Sometimes,Never
", header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = "")

# Levels F, M (alphabetically sorted -> 1, 2)
df$Sex_fact <- factor(df$Sex)

lookup_freq <- c(
  "0" = "Never",
  "1" = "Sometimes",
  "3" = "Always"
)
df$Q1 <- factor(df$Question_01, levels = lookup_freq, labels = names(lookup_freq))
df$Q2 <- factor(df$Question_02, levels = lookup_freq, labels = names(lookup_freq))
df$Q3 <- factor(df$Question_03, levels = lookup_freq, labels = names(lookup_freq))
df$Q4 <- factor(df$Question_04, levels = lookup_freq, labels = names(lookup_freq))

df$Total_score <- as.numeric(df$Q1) + as.numeric(df$Q2) + as.numeric(df$Q3) + as.numeric(df$Q4)

print(df)
```

The `Total_score` should just be all the answers added up, according to the `0`, `1`, `3` codes. The result I get is incorrect, and I understand that this is because it uses the numeric values of the factor, which is just `1`, `2`, `3`. But I don't know how to set the levels to the desired codes, using the list I've got in `lookup_freq`.

```
   DateOfBirth Sex Question_01 Question_02 Question_03 Question_04 Sex_fact Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Total_score
1   12-03-2001   M   Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never        M  1  1  0  0           6
2   21-08-1988   F      Always       Never      Always   Sometimes        F  3  0  3  1           9
3   30-11-1985   F      Always      Always   Sometimes       Never        F  3  3  1  0           9
4   01-04-2001   M   Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never        M  1  1  0  0           6
5   12-12-1986   M      Always   Sometimes      Always       Never        M  3  1  3  0           9
6   19-02-1982   F      Always      Always       Never   Sometimes        F  3  3  0  1           9
7   11-05-1980   M   Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never        M  1  1  0  0           6
8   01-06-2000   F      Always   Sometimes      Always      Always        F  3  1  3  3          11
9   20-11-1981   F       Never       Never       Never   Sometimes        F  0  0  0  1           5
10  30-07-1982   M       Never       Never   Sometimes       Never        M  0  0  1  0           5
```

So my question is, is it possible to create a Factor column with the labels `Never`, `Sometimes`, `Always` but with the underlying levels as `0`, `1`, `3` ? Or is it better to just create new columns and replace the character label values with the integer score values?

Or what is the best way to use a lookup variable, similar to `lookup_freq`? Because I've got more questionnaires with similarly coded answer columns, sometimes with 4 or 5 answer possibilities.

Comment: No, it's not possible to modify the underlying levels of a factor.  One way to do what you want (the best way? maybe) is to write a function that converts the observed values to the score you want.  Then use that function when you want to compute the total score.

Comment: the underlying levels will be 1,2,3 and since they are numeric, you can always do math with them in any way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1: extra level

A hack, but you can create factors such that they resolve to 1, 2, and 4 (instead of 0, 1, and 3) and subtract 1 for each column you're reference.

```r
### ...
lookup_freq <- c("Never", "Sometimes", "Who Cares", "Always")
as.numeric(factor(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Always"), levels=lookup_freq)) - 1
# [1] 0 1 3

df$Q1 <- factor(df$Question_01, levels = lookup_freq)
df$Q2 <- factor(df$Question_02, levels = lookup_freq)
df$Q3 <- factor(df$Question_03, levels = lookup_freq)
df$Q4 <- factor(df$Question_04, levels = lookup_freq)

(as.numeric(df$Q1) + as.numeric(df$Q2) + as.numeric(df$Q3) + as.numeric(df$Q4)) - 4
#  [1]  2  7  7  2  7  7  2 10  1  1

# or more clearly
rowSums(sapply(df[,c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")], as.numeric)-1)
#  [1]  2  7  7  2  7  7  2 10  1  1
```

## Option 2: lookup dictionary

```r
# original `df` with no factors
lookup_dict <- c("Never"=0, "Sometimes"=1, "Always"=3)
rowSums(sapply(df[,3:6], function(i) lookup_dict[i]))
# Sometimes    Always    Always Sometimes    Always    Always Sometimes    Always     Never     Never 
#         2         7         7         2         7         7         2        10         1         1
```

Comment: Somehow option 2 with the dictionary lookup makes the most sense to me. I'm used to dictionaries like `0=Never` etc., but R only support character keys not integers, which got me confused initially. But you're right, I can just do `df$Q1 <- lookup_dict[df$Question_01]` etc. for the columns, and then `df$total <- df$Q1 + df$Q2 + df$Q3 + df$Q4`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `recode`:

```
df %>%
   mutate(TotalScore = across(starts_with('Question'),
         ~as.numeric(recode(.x, !!!deframe(rev(enframe(lookup_freq))))))|>
           rowSums())

   DateOfBirth Sex Question_01 Question_02 Question_03 Question_04 Sex_fact TotalScore
1   12-03-2001   M   Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never        M          2
2   21-08-1988   F      Always       Never      Always   Sometimes        F          7
3   30-11-1985   F      Always      Always   Sometimes       Never        F          7
4   01-04-2001   M   Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never        M          2
5   12-12-1986   M      Always   Sometimes      Always       Never        M          7
6   19-02-1982   F      Always      Always       Never   Sometimes        F          7
7   11-05-1980   M   Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never        M          2
8   01-06-2000   F      Always   Sometimes      Always      Always        F         10
9   20-11-1981   F       Never       Never       Never   Sometimes        F          1
10  30-07-1982   M       Never       Never   Sometimes       Never        M          1
```

---

In base R you could use extraction operator as shown below:

```
a <- df[, startsWith(names(df), 'Question')]
b <- setNames(names(lookup_freq), lookup_freq)[unlist(a)]
cbind(a, Total_score = rowsum(as.numeric(b), c(row(a))))

   Question_01 Question_02 Question_03 Question_04 Total_score
1    Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never           2
2       Always       Never      Always   Sometimes           7
3       Always      Always   Sometimes       Never           7
4    Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never           2
5       Always   Sometimes      Always       Never           7
6       Always      Always       Never   Sometimes           7
7    Sometimes   Sometimes       Never       Never           2
8       Always   Sometimes      Always      Always          10
9        Never       Never       Never   Sometimes           1
10       Never       Never   Sometimes       Never           1
```

You could also use `match`

```
 b <- names(lookup_freq[match(unlist(a), lookup_freq)])
```

and run the other parts as shown above

Comment: I'm new to R and I can't wrap my head around any of this syntax, sorry. Thanks for the answer though.